# How do I note two vectors at once?

Tags: matrices, notation

I want to note down two vectors at once.
Is that possible?

I would image something like $\vec{v}, \vec{w}=[1, 2], [2, 4]$.

Comment: What is stopping you from writing $\vec{v}=[1,2],\vec{w}=[2,4]$?  That seems perfectly concise to me and avoids needlessly confusing notation.

Comment: Keep in mind, the point of notation is to convey the intended meaning clearly and efficiently, with the emphasis on clearly.  There's no sense in sacrificing clarity to save a couple of keystrokes.

Comment: @lulu Writing down the vectors in matrix form (as in Ria's answer) doesn't threaten the clarity, in my opinion?

Comment: @zaira, but it is neither more concise nor more helpful for the reader.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could say  $(\vec{v}, \vec{w})=([1, 2], [2, 4])$.

As is mentioned in the comments, this is not necessarily the best way to go. Defining them "separately," i.e., $\vec{v}=[1, 2]$, $\vec{w}=[2, 4]$ is probably better.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you could try using matrices:

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{c}
  \mathbf{\ \color{red}{v}}\\
  \mathbf{\color{green}{w}}
\end{array}
\right] = 
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
  \color{red}{1} & \color{red}{2}\\
  \color{green}{2} & \color{green}{4}
\end{array}
\right]$$
where, $v=(1,2)$ and $w=(2,4)$.